# WeasyPrint and Bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, weasyprint

So I have a very simple template that I am testing with WeasyPrint. If render the template as a regular webpage it renders just fine.  If I try generatinga PDF the styling dissapears.  The only time the PDF will generate properly is when I remove the bootstrap reference. Does anyone have any thoughts on why styling would not work as soon as I introduce the bootstrap css files? I have tried some Bootstrap3 and Bootstrap2 files. Local and CDN served.

The Template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
{%  load static from staticfiles %}
{%  block head %}
    <head>
    {% block css %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%  static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%  static "css/main.css" %}">
    {% endblock css %}
    </head>
{% endblock head %}
<body>
{% block content %}
    <div id="content" class="container">
        <div id="logo" class="col-md-3">
            <img src="{%  static "images/logo_small.png" %}">
        </div>
        <div id="heading" class="col-md-6">
            <h1>Packing Slip</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h2>{{ packslip_id }}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

My View:

```
class WeasyPDF(TemplateView):
template_name = 'jinja2/Shipping/test_pdf.html'


def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    packslip_id = kwargs.get('packslip_id')
    context= {'packslip_id': packslip_id }
    template_string = render_to_string(self.template_name, context)
    html = HTML(string=template_string, base_url=request.build_absolute_uri())
    main_doc = html.render()
    pdf = main_doc.write_pdf()
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    #Download as attachment
    # response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=packslip-{0}.pdf'.format(packslip_id)
    # Display in browser
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=packslip-{0}.pdf'.format(packslip_id)
    return response
```

Finally the urls.py entry

```
    url(r'^weasypdf/(?P<packslip_id>\d+)$', WeasyPDF.as_view(), name='weasypdf'),
```

Comment: You should use stylesheets keyword argument with write_pdf method and pass your stylesheets there instead.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to render the CSS into your html object:
html = HTML(string=template_string, base_url=request.build_absolute_uri(), stylesheet="filename.css")

Once that is done, then Weasyprint will render it into the HTML object for display in both PDF and HTML

Answer (score 0):

You should put the stylesheet location in your view, not in your template.

```
class WeasyPDF(TemplateView):
template_name = 'jinja2/Shipping/test_pdf.html'


def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    packslip_id = kwargs.get('packslip_id')
    context= {'packslip_id': packslip_id }
    template_string = render_to_string(self.template_name, context)
    html = HTML(string=template_string, base_url=request.build_absolute_uri())
    main_doc = html.render()
    pdf = main_doc.write_pdf(
    stylesheets=[
        # Change this to suit your css path
        settings.BASE_DIR + 'css/bootstrap.min.css',
        settings.BASE_DIR + 'css/main.css',
    ],
    )
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    #Download as attachment
    # response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=packslip-{0}.pdf'.format(packslip_id)
    # Display in browser
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename=packslip-{0}.pdf'.format(packslip_id)
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1: Use Weasyprint CSS styling

```
styles = CSS(settings.STATIC_ROOT + "/css/bootstrap.min.css")
http_response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/pdf")
http_response[
    "Content-Disposition"
] = 'attachment;filename="pdf_file.pdf"'
HTML(string=html_string, base_url=request.build_absolute_uri()).write_pdf(
    http_response,
    stylesheets=[
        styles,
    ],
)
return http_response
```

Once that is done, then Weasyprint will render it into the HTML object for display in both PDF and HTML

**See the weasyprint styling documentation [here](https://doc.courtbouillon.org/weasyprint/stable/first_steps.html#instantiating-html-and-css-objects)**

### Solution 2: Use regular external static css in django

**In your django template use**

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
.
.
.
    <link  href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" >
.
.
.
```

**In your view use**

```
HTML(string=html_string, base_url=request.build_absolute_uri()).write_pdf(
    http_response,
    presentational_hints=True,
)
return http_response
```

Comment: `from weasyprint import HTML, CSS`